# geometric problem solved with Pigeon Hole Principle

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

The problem is:

Show that among any 5 points in a equilateral triangle of unit side length, there are 2 whose distance is at most 1/2 units apart.

Comment: We encourage you to accept an answer to each of your questions, when you find one that's particularly helpful. To accept an answer, just click on the $\large\checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept. You can only accept *one* answer per question asked, but you do get two reputation points each time you accept one answer to a question.

Answer (score 13):

Break the equilateral triangle into four smaller triangles by joining the midpoints of the sides. Now we have four holes and five pegions hence three must be at least one triangle which contains at least two points. The distance between the two points cannot exceed the side of the triangle.Also the side of the triangles formed is $\frac1{2}$ and the result follows . Hence  among any 5 points in a equilateral triangle of unit side length, there are 2 whose distance is at most 1/2 units apart.