# Least distance between two points in an equilateral triangle

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

Five points lie inside an equilateral triangle of side 2 units.Prove that at least 2 points are no more than a unit distance apart.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1685450/maximum-distance-between-points-in-a-triangle -- part (a) ; http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476243/geometric-problem-solved-with-pigeon-hole-principle/476254#476254 ; etc., etc.  (This question has come up repeatedly. Search on:  five points equilateral triangle)

Answer (score 1):

Connect the midpoints of the sides to each other. This divides the original triangle into four smaller, congruent equilateral triangles of side 1 unit. You have five points and only four triangles, so two points must be in one of the triangles. They can't be more than one unit apart.